# Object literal pattern jQuery Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

While learning how to structure my code ( little steps I'm giving so to write better code ) I develop this simple slider with thumbnails and a main image. I used (as far as I understood) an object literal pattern to develop the slider object.

What it does is basically that when you click on the thumbnail, you get the src and change the main image src. Although it is working, my question is: is there is a better way of doing this ( for sure there is ) and optimize code? Any suggestion will help.

Here is my HTML

```
    <section class="product-slider">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div>
                        <img class="main-pic" src="images/single-product.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="thumnails-container">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="thumb"><img src="images/single-product.png"></li>
                            <li class="selected thumb"><img src="images/single-product1.png"></li>
                            <li class="thumb"><img src="images/single-product2.png"></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

And here my jQuery

```js
thumbSlider.init();

var thumbSlider = {

  init: function(){
    this.cacheDom();
    this.bindEvents();
  },
  cacheDom: function() {
    this.$slider = $('.product-slider');
    this.$thumb = this.$slider.find('.thumb');
    this.$mainPic = this.$slider.find('.main-pic');
  },
  bindEvents: function(){
    this.$thumb.click(this.getSrc.bind(this));
  },
  getSrc: function(event){
    console.log(event.target);
    var src = $(event.target).attr('src');
    this.$mainPic.attr('src', src);
  }
};
```

PS: For this slider, the thumbnail and main image will be the same image scaled with some CSS.

Thanks.

Comment: You might be interesting in the sister site: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks. I Will post there.